# Using one to many join to *.xlsx in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins, excel

I'm working with ArcMap 10 and have some trouble joining a shapefile and a .xlsx file.

The .xlsx contains sensor data (CO2, NO2 etc.) without location information. The shapefile contains all the sensor locations. Sounds easy but here is the problem:

The .xlsx file contains data from multiple points in time (every 5 seconds of a single day). It looks like this in ArcMap:

[image]

And the Shapefile attribute table looks very simple:

[image]

I Want to join the two based on ID, which is the matching sensor number. A basic join obviously won't do the trick. I tried to mess around with creating a Query Table but could not make it work. How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps this topic might help: [About joining and relating tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/)

Comment: If you convert the non-table spreadsheet to a table (using legal column names -- alphanumeric and underscore only) and add an index on the ID column, you'll have a much easier time with the one-to-many join.

Comment: Joseph provided a good link. Note that you might need to save that XLSX file to XLS. Arc might throw unnecessary errors at you for using the newer Excel doc version.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: What precisely have you tried?  For example, have you tried converting the Excel worksheet to a table, and then using a relate?  If so, can you describe your steps to show where what you expect/need departs from what you are observing, please?  The documentation linked to by @Joseph is the same place that I would recommend starting.